# private TestInitialize method is not initializing objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mstest, private-members

I have a test class that should basically be like the following:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTest
{
    private MyClass o1;
    private MyClass o2;

    [TestInitialize]
    private void PrepareObjects()
    {
        o1 = new MyClass();
        o2 = new MyClass();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestEquality()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(o1.Equals(o2));
    }        
}
```

But when I run the tests, I get a `NullReferenceException`. If I put breakpoints inside `PrepareObjects` and `TestEquality` then I can see that `TestInitialize` has not been invoked by the time `TestEquality` is.

Changing `PrepareObjects` from private to public fixes this. Why?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The test framework is only looking for public methods. Similarly, if you make `TestEquality` private, *that* won't run, and if you make `MyTest` internal, then *nothing* shown will run.

Comment: The simplicity and retrospective obviousness of this answer reminds me of the hour of my life that I will never get back.

Comment: @Zyo why? From the compiler's perspective, there's nothing unusual about that

Comment: @MarcGravell I have the impression that TestInitiaze is only used to be run BEFORE unit test... if that method is not invoked because it's private... how can it be called? or for what usages can TestInitialize be put on a privates methods?